# Error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, django

I'm using a well known library.

So I don't think the problem is with the code. The error and console are referring to this line--`typed.js:1`:

`import { initializer } from './initializer.js';`

Here's the script tag:

```
{% block javascript %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/typed/typed.js' %}"></script>  
    ...
{% endblock javascript %}
```

what am I doing wrong?

edit: I see it's ES syntax. I'm using chrome 63 and it's been in chrome since 61, so that can't be it either.

Edit: [Here is the JS library I'm trying to use](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/). How would you go about incorporating this in your django project?

Comment: Did you want to use {{ }} from  the django templating language in your included javascript file?

Comment: @Rechunk No. The code in the JS file was not written by me. It's from a library called 'typed.js'. It's written in ES syntax and is correct. I cannot figure out why Django isn't registering this syntax while having no problems with any of my other js files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the original Typed library was being used which is written in ES.

Use the transpiled version to be sure it works with all browsers.

See here for specific browser support information:
https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module

Answer (score 0):

Have you maybe forgot to end the block?

```
{% block javascript %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/typed/typed.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock javascript %}
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not it. I have ended the block